# Disable warnings from base module + load Moose/Test2::V0

Tags: perl, warnings, moose, strict

In our app we have a common base module that enables `strict`, `warnings` and some other pragmas for every file that it `use`d from. It also enables signatures and disables the warning about signatures being experimental:

```perl
sub import {
    warnings->unimport('experimental::signatures');
    feature->import('signatures');
}
```

When testing in CI with Perl 5.32 (which still considered signatures experimental) I still get a load of warnings about experimental because we loaded other modules like Moose or Test2::V0 *after* our base module.

```perl
use MyApp::Base;  # initial setup, enables signatures

use Carp;
use Moose;   # unconditionally enables experimental warnings again
```

Is there any way to permanently disable a specific warning regardless of other modules making `use warnings` in our scope?

I wanted to use our base class as *first* import in every code to allow all kinds of initial setup tasks. Do I really need to handcraft the order to move all Moose/Test2::V0/… imports above like this?

```perl
use Moose;    # these must come first
use Test2::V0;

use MyApp::Base;    # now we can run our common setup

use Carp;    # now we can import other stuff, too
```

How is this handled in other projects with a common base class?

Comment: No. You could only edit/replace Moose::import

Comment: If loading your module after Moose does the trick can you not write another module that does only that (unimport etc -- and perhaps other final configuration actions) and load that last?

Comment: @zdim I’m not quite sure what you mean by “does only that”. I already had the thought of creating subclass base package like `MyApp::Base::Moose` or `MyApp::Base::Test2V0` that do all the setup and load the named CPAN package but it feels like overengineering. Did you mean that or what else?

Comment: @DanielBöhmer If I understood the question correctly, your `MyApp::Base` does something (the `unimport`) that, if loaded after Moose, takes care of those warrnings.  Can you then have another module, that only does that `unimport`, to load after Moose? (Actually just load it last.)  A separate tiny unit that only takes care of those warnings.

Comment: @zdim: Yes, that is a possible solution. I decided against that because I wanted to reduce, at least not increase, the number of repeated statements (boilerplate).

Comment: I’ve just posted a Merge Request in our project: https://gitlab.com/coocook/coocook/-/merge_requests/239 Right now it’s open for comments and the proposed change at the time of writing this is: `use Test2::V0 -no_warnings => 1` for Test2 and an extension to our common base class to handle imports of `Moose` and its derivates.

Comment: @DanielBöhmer "_I decided against that because I wanted to reduce..._" -- yeah, I got that, I thought your question is clear in seeking a nice and clean setup.  My point is that it may not be feasible (or really possible) to elegantly handle all possible changes other libraries may make to your configuration just by loading your lib first.  So it may make sense to add one final call (loading a module) that finalizes configuration you want, in this case disables those warnings.  But of course there may well be other solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Since you apparently do have to "unimport" *after* loading libraries that re-enable those warnings, why not have another module that does only such final configuration, in this case the needed un-importing?  Then that one is loaded last.

A simplest example

```
package StopWarnings;
# Final configuration steps

use warnings;
use v5.32;

sub import {
    warnings->unimport('experimental::signatures');
    feature->import('signatures');
}

1;
```

A program that uses it

```
use warnings;
use v5.32;

use feature qw(signatures);  # instead of MyApp::Base

use Test2::V0;
use Moose;

use FindBin qw($RealBin);
use lib $RealBin;

use StopWarnings;  # when this is commented out there are warnings

sub greet($name) { say "Hello $name" }

greet('Prudence');
```

This is indeed yet another module to load but having a final configuration step makes some sense.  With time, other last-thing configuration needs may find it useful.